# let lldb's working directory be XCode's project directory

Tags: xcode, lldb

When debugging in XCode (8.0), I'd like to have `lldb`'s working directory to be the respective project directory.

What I'd like to achieve is to access project files from processes that I launch in `lldb` or in `.lldbinit`, and I'd like to access them without having to type/know the full path.

For example, I'd like to spawn a local web server with `php -S localhost:2345` within the project directory, such that - in debugging mode - I can simulate downloading well known files (instead of accessing them through the bundle).

I've also tried to use environment variables, e.g. `platform shell -- cd $PROJECT_DIR` or similar, yet without success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Python interpreter to change lldb's working directory.  For instance:

```
(lldb) script os.chdir("/tmp/")
(lldb) script os.getcwd()
'/private/tmp'
(lldb) platform shell echo $PWD
/private/tmp
```

Note, this doesn't change Xcode's working directory since lldb actually runs as a service (`lldb-rpc-server`) rather than being a library linked directly into Xcode.

Comment: Is there a way to get the directory of the XCode-Project just having launched 'lldb', e.g. something like `script os.chdir("$PROJECT_DIR")`, instead of having to "hard-code" the path for every different project?

Comment: lldb doesn't know about Xcode projects, and Xcode doesn't pass the project variables down to lldb, so there's no trivial way to do this.  You can use the lldb Python API's to find the location of the source files built into your binary, so if you can find your way from the source files to the project, that might get you want you want.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know; It seems that this is related to "project-specific .lldbinit - files", as with that I could overcome the need to change "my" single .lldbinit-file for every different project then.